# Definition of $\text{Vect}_0^n(S^k)$ in Hatcher's K-Theory

Tags: general-topology, vector-bundles, spheres

I'm reading Hatcher's [book on K-Theory](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf), and on pages 25-26, he talks about real vector bundles over $S^k$. He defines the object $\text{Vect}_0^n(S^k)$ as

> the
>   n dimensional vector bundles over $S^k$ with an orientation specified in the fiber over
>   one point $x_0 \in S^{k−1}$, with the equivalence relation of isomorphism preserving the
>   orientation of the fiber over $x_0$.

I'm interpreting this to mean that an element of $\text{Vect}_0^n(S^k)$ is a vector bundle plus a specified orientation of the fiber over some arbitrary point $x_0$ (chosen for convenience to lie on the "equator" $S^{k-1}$ of $S^k$). Another way to say this is, the trivializing functions $\phi_\alpha:\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)\rightarrow U_\alpha\times\mathbb{R}^n$ must send the oriented basis of  $\pi^{-1}(x_0)$ to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $\alpha$ with $x_0\in U_\alpha$. And we consider any two vector bundles to be equivalent if they are isomorphic AND have the same specified orientation on $x_0$.

However, I'm worried this interpretation is incorrect, or there is something else I'm missing, because later he says:

> The map $\text{Vect}^n_0(S^k)\rightarrow\text{Vect}^n(S^k)$ that forgets the orientation over $x_0$ is a surjection that is two-to-one except on vector bundles that have an automorphism (an isomorphism from the bundle to itself) reversing the orientation of the fiber over $x_0$, where it is one-to-one.

According to my interpretation, this is exactly backwards. I would assume that if a vector bundle has an automorphism that reverses the orientation of $x_0$, there would be TWO elements of $\text{Vect}^n_0(S^k)$ that map to it, one for each orientation of $x_0$, while if a vector bundle does NOT have an automorphism that reverses the orientation of $x_0$, then there would only be one element in $\text{Vect}^n_0(S^k)$ that maps to it.

Can someone point out where I am thinking about this incorrectly, or just provide more details on the object $\text{Vect}^n_0(S^k)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $\text{Vect}^n(S^k)$ are equivalence classes $[E]$ of $n$-dimensional vector bundles $E$ over $S^k$, where $E, E'$ are equivalent iff there exists a bundle isomorphism $\phi : E \to E'$. The elements of $\text{Vect}_0^n(S^k)$ are equivalence classes $[E,\omega]$ of pairs $(E,\omega)$ consisting of an $n$-dimensional vector bundle $E$ over $S^k$ and an orientation $\omega$ of the fiber over $x_0$ (which has two orientations $\omega^\pm$), where $(E,\omega), (E',\omega')$ are equivalent iff there exists a bundle isomorphism $\phi : E \to E'$ such that $\phi(\omega)  = \omega'$.

The map
$$P : \text{Vect}_0^n(S^k) \to \text{Vect}^n(S^k),\quad P:[E,\omega] \mapsto [E]$$
is obviously a surjection. We certainly have
$$P^{-1}([E]) = \{ [E,\omega^+], [E,\omega^-] \} .$$
But  $[E,\omega^+] = [E,\omega^-]$ iff there exists a bundle isomorphism $\phi : E \to E$ such that $\phi(\omega^+)  = \omega^-$, i.e. a bundle  automorphism on $E$ which reverses the orientation of the fiber over $x_0$.

Thus Hatcher is right.

Comment: Ok this cleared everything up. I think my issue was I was thinking about there being some intrinsic definition of "positive" orientation, but of course there is no intrinsic definition of positive orientation, there are just two DIFFERENT orientations. So orientation-reversing automorphisms are also automorphisms in $\text{Vect}_0^n$.

Comment: Ok, after thinking about this a bit, o have a follow-up question. With your definition of $\text{Vect}_0^n$, is it obvious that the elements of this space are in bijective correspondence with the homotopy classes of clutching functions that take $x_0$ to a positive matrix?

Comment: Naively, it seems like the clutching function described by some $h_\pm$ could be homotopic to the clutching function defined by the orientation-reversed versions of $h_\pm$, is there some reason that can't happen?

Comment: Clutching fuinctions are not really related to $\text{Vect}_0^n$. Each element of $\text{Vect}^n$ corresponds to a homotopy class of clutching functions, so each element of $\text{Vect}_0^n$ corresponds to a homotopy class of clutching functions + an orientation of the fiber over $x_0$, and these two components are independent. Nevertheless I think you may be right that $[E,\omega^+] = [E,\omega^-]$ iff the clutching function $h$ for $E$ is homotopic to the orientation reversed clutching function $h'$.